# Custom Button In product detail page

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, product, layout, template

[image: Product Page]

I need to make button near add to cart button without touching core template files. Kindly help me in this case?

I am developing a extension. When Install that extension, the button should be created. what should I do for that?

### Problem in Detail

I am working on a **shirt design plug in** in which we can buy a shirt and we can **design** & buy that shirt too. I need to put a button for **designing shirt**. By clicking on it we can design shirt. I've done everything except adding button. If I add button by modifying **core templates**, I can not use plug in anywhere.

So only I am asking, Is there any way to add button in product **without modifying core templates**?

Comment: almost gave +1 for putting up Johny Bravo... Whoohaa... There's a pretty man in my room... Call 911 for help... Wait a second.... It is only me

Comment: You could add a dependency on `Mage_Catalog` and add a custom layoutfile for frontend. You can add a section for `<catalog_product_view>` and `<reference name="product.info.addtocart"><action method="setTemplate"><template>myown/file.phtml</template></action></reference>`

Comment: Yes, You are correct, I've already found it. Anyway thanks for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Just modify your themes template file to add a new button or change the existing 'add to cart' button depending on what you're wanting to do. No core files need to be touched for template edits.

The path to the template file is the below for the product detail page like your question title specifies yet your screenshot is showing the product list page.

```
/app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

Comment: I am developing a extension. When Install that extension, the button should be created. what should I do for that?

Comment: You should have specified that (and any other important details) in your original question then as this requires a completely different answer. Impossible to answer based on the minimal information you've provided, my best guess would be you'll need to package with a layout XML that references a template file in your extension and appends to `product.info.addtocart` but there are loads of ways depending on exactly what you want to achieve... Close voting.

Comment: I've updated my Question.. @zigojacko

Comment: What functionality do you expect to happen when said button is clicked?

Comment: need to redirect to tool page where we design shirts  with product id @zigojacko

Comment: If all the button is going to do is redirect your customer to another page to customise their product why don't you just package a template file in with your extension (e.g. `/template/extension_name/customise.phtml`) and then declare this block in your extension XML like (`<reference name="product.info.addtocart"><block type="your_block_type" name="product.design.tshirt" as="tshirt-design" after="-"  template="extension_name/customise.phtml"/></reference>`)?

Comment: `<default>
  <reference name="product.info.addtocart">
    <block type="fabric_tool/tool" name="product.design.tshirt" as="tshirt-design" after="-" template="fabric/tool/design_div.phtml"/>
  </reference>
    </default>` is this one correct? but It makes no effect..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21851/discussion-between-vivek-aasaithambi-and-zigojacko).